# 他の関数から関数の中の変数を取り出す

Tags: python

VoiceTextのGUI操作をkivyで作っているのですが、nameerrorが出てしまって動きません。どうやったらいいか教えて下さい。
main.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*
from pyVoiceText import VoiceText
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase, DEFAULT_FONT
from kivy.resources import resource_add_path
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

resource_add_path('/System/Library/Fonts/')
LabelBase.register(DEFAULT_FONT, 'ヒラギノ明朝 ProN.ttc')
#Window.size = (500, 350)

class CustomSpinner(Spinner):
    pass

class MainRoot(BoxLayout):
    talk = 'テキスト'
    text = StringProperty('')

    def on_speaker(self, speaker):
        speaker = "'"+speaker+"'"
        print(speaker)
        return speaker

    def on_format(self, format):
        format = "'out"+format+"'"
        print(format)
        return format

    def on_command(self):
        self.text = self.ids.textInput.text
        text = self.text
        api_key = 'xxxxx'

        voice_text = VoiceText(api_key)
        mp3 = voice_text.fetch(text, speaker, format)

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = 'VoiceText'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

main.kv

```
MainRoot:

<MainRoot>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        CustomSpinner:
            text: '話者を選択して下さい'
            values: 'show', 'haruka', 'hikari', 'takeru', 'santa', 'bear'
            size_hint: None, None
            size: root.width, root.height/4
            pos_hint: {"x":0, "top":1}
            on_text: root.on_speaker(self.text)

        CustomSpinner:
            text: 'フォーマット形式を選択して下さい'
            values: '.wav', '.ogg', '.mp3'
            size_hint: None, None
            size: root.width, root.height/4
            pos_hint: {"x":0, "top":1}
            on_text: root.on_format(self.text)

        Label:
            size: root.width, root.height/4
            text: root.talk

        TextInput:
            id: textInput
            size: root.width, root.height/4
            multiline: False
            text: ''
            hint_text: 'しゃべらせたい言葉を入力して下さい'

        Button:
            size: root.width, root.height/4
            text: '実行'
            on_press: root.on_command()
```

Comment: エラーのログを省略せずにすべてコピー＆ペーストしていただくことは可能でしょうか？　Python はログにどこでエラーが起きたのかの情報も含まれているので、ログがあると嬉しいです。個人情報等が含まれている部分は伏せ字にして頂いて構いません。「編集」から追記していただければと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kivyはまったく知らないのですが、もし、`on_speaker`と`on_format`に渡されたものを後で`on_command`の中で使いたいという質問なのであれば、`MainRoot`オブジェクトの`self`に保存してはだめでしょうか？

```py
    def on_speaker(self, speaker):
        self.selected_speaker = ...

    def on_format(self, format):
        self.selected_format = ...

    def on_command(self):
        ...
        mp3 = voice_text.fetch(text, self.selected_speaker, self.selected_format)
```